# How to use Button with Behavior in Silverlight Legend?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

I'm trying to use a button with behavior in the MapLayerTemplate of an Esri Silverlight SDK 2.1 legend.

When I click the button and then drag on the map, the map pans instead of showing a selection rectangle.

The behavior code is pulled from [this sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.1/samples/start.htm#GraphicsActions), while the legend is from [this sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.1/samples/start.htm#LegendWithTemplates).

If I put the same xaml code within the layoutroot, it works as expected - I see a selection rectangle and the selection completes successfully.

```
<esri:Legend x:Name="MyLegend" Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}"  
            LayerIDs="ProjectPolys,AssetPoints,AssetLines,BaseLayers,WaterInfrastructure,SewerInfrastructure"
            LayerItemsMode="Tree" 
            ShowOnlyVisibleLayers="False"
            Refreshed="Legend_Refreshed">
    <esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}"
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}">                                
                </CheckBox>
                <Button Content="Select">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                            <esriBehaviors:SpatialQueryAction         
                                DrawMode="Rectangle"         
                                LayerID="MyGraphicsLayer"         
                                Url="http://hq-gis-01/ArcGIS/rest/services/WaterInfrastructure2/MapServer/15"
                                Symbol="{StaticResource GraphicsLayerFillSymbol}"         
                                TargetName="MyMap" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </Button>
                <Slider Maximum="1" Value="{Binding Layer.Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="50" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </esri:Legend.MapLayerTemplate>
    <esri:Legend.LayerTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Label}"
            IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsInScaleRange}" >
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </esri:Legend.LayerTemplate>
</esri:Legend>
```

**Update:**
Following Seth's suggestion I tried wiring the trigger in the code-behind.  I get the same results.  The code behind approach fails for the button in the datatemplate, but works for the one on a stackpanel sibling to the map.

```
private void Assign_Behavior_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Actions.SpatialQueryAction sqa = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Actions.SpatialQueryAction();
    sqa.DrawMode = DrawMode.Rectangle;
    sqa.LayerID = "MyGraphicsLayer";
    sqa.Url = @"http://hq-gis-01/ArcGIS/rest/services/WaterInfrastructure2/MapServer/15";
    sqa.Symbol = LayoutRoot.Resources["GraphicsLayerFillSymbol"] as Symbol;
    sqa.TargetName = "MyMap";

    var et = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger("Click");
    et.Actions.Add(sqa);
    var triggerColl = System.Windows.Interactivity.Interaction.GetTriggers(button);
    triggerColl.Add(et);
}
```

I'm beginning to think this is not an Esri issue - I can't find an example anywhere showing how to attach trigger actions from buttons in a datatemplate.

Comment: What happens when you click the button?  Does it enter the Assign_Behavior_Click event and then do nothing?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate this issue, it may be a bug with ESRI's API.  You can put a Click event in the Select button to hit the code-behind and then use this technique to call the action:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/3696-Measure-Action-in-Code?p=11969&viewfull=1#post11969

As Dominique states, it's probably not recommended to use Actions in the code-behind, however in this case, I don't see any alternative.

Comment: Thanks Seth.  I've updated my question with your suggestion.